# Certain commits not showing up during git rebase -i

Tags: git

I'm working on a poc branch which is off of a main branch. Over time I've made multiple commits to this branch, and I've either rebased/merged from the main branch into this branch to pull in changes. I am trying to clean up my commits on this branch. I've managed to squash some commits, but now I'm running into a serious issue.

Here is the current main branch history (most recent on top to oldest):

```
80164051 reorganizing file structure
41ecd3dd changing build systems
```

Here is the current POC branch history after my changes (most recent on top to oldest):

```
0dca1c21 adding functionality for X
5b015e27 merged from main. apparently i rebased last time, not merged
13def9fe merged from main
80164051 reorganizing file structure
039ff465 add a model
a2a6378d add more functions
a2143aa3 add some functions
477f9e9f init
41ecd3dd changing build systems
```

Basically, the history of this branch is that after commit `41ecd3dd`, I made 4 commits on my POC branch, then a big file restructuring was introduced in main branch, so I tried getting those changes into my POC branch. I must have screwed something up during that process, and ended up with commits `13def9fe` and `5b015e27`. But I don't remember what specifically I screwed up. I believe I renamed the branch at some point.

Now, I am trying to squash further, but im not getting the history that i want in the interactive rebase menu. When I run `git rebase -i HEAD~3`, I get the following:

```
pick 13def9f merged from main
pick 8016405 reorganizing file structure
pick 0dca1c2 adding functionality for X

# Rebase 039ff46..0dca1c2 onto 039ff46 (3 commands)
```

As you can see, the commit `5b015e27 merged from main. apparently i rebased last time, not merged` is not showing up in the interactive rebase menu. Also, I don't want to coalesce any of my changes in `0dcac1c2` with `8016405`. I want these to remain separate commits.

What I want in the end is for the poc branch git history like this:

```
0dca1c2 adding functionality for X
8016405 reorganizing file structure
<some hash> squash of 039ff465, a2a6378d, a2143aa3, 477f9e9f
41ecd3dd changing build systems
```

Is it possible to achieve the above? if so, how?

Comment: Update: I've gotten around this issue by making a new branch off of mainline, and cherry-picking the latest commit 0dca1c2 off of my poc branch into this new branch. This gives me a very clean git history that I want `41ecd3dd -> 8016405 -> 0dca1c2 (HEAD)`

Comment: `git log --oneline --graph` gives a clear history graph.  If the rebase TODO is not like what you expected, `HEAD~3` is not the proper value.

Comment: @ElpieKay what was unexpected was commit `5b015e27 ` never showing up in rebase no matter how many commits i went back

Comment: `5b015e27` looks like a merge commit. A merge commit does not show up in the todo.

Comment: Need to sldo use `--rebase-merges`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you don't see these commits is: a plain `git rebase` will drop merge commits from its list.

This is documented with the [`-r|--rebase-merges` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--r) :

> By default, a rebase will simply drop merge commits from the todo list, and put the rebased commits into a single, linear branch.

(note: it is a bit surprising to have this information only with the option which precisely tries to cancel it ... ;) )

---

Note that, in most cases, this is actually what you want: at our place we use rebase to keep a simple linear history on our branches, so we do not to have merges surviving a `git rebase` operation.

If you happen to be in a situation where you want to replay merges though, you may use this `-r|--rebase-merges` option.

Read the doc (link above, or `git help rebase` from your terminal) to see all the details about it.